# What does "CLEAR" mean on a land survey map?

Tags: land-survey

I paid for a land survey of my house lot, and there was one term on the survey map that I wasn't 100% sure about: "CLEAR".  It's used on the map to refer to a short distance (e.g. `0.1' CLEAR` or `0.2' CLEAR`).

Is CLEAR short for "clearance"?  If yes, does that mean that my house is 0.1 feet and 0.2 feet, respectively, away from the property line?  Or does it more likely mean that my house is on the property line and those small distances are measurement errors?

The house is in California if this term is locale-specific.

[image]

Comment: As you have also guessed, I would assume it means the clearance distance between the house and the boundary line (or whatever that bold dark line is).  I reckon it is probably the same as the 2.2 and the 2.3 at the other side of the house (and the 2.6 on the same side), but explicitly marked "CLEAR" because the gap is so small in the picture as to be invisible.  I can't find anything to support this guess though.  You may do better asking on a CAD/drafting site rather than a GIS site.

Comment: I'd recommend you ask the folks you paid to explain what they meant by the mark.